# Oracle Client 32 bit on windows 2012 64 bit

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Please clarify the following doubts

1) Can we install `oracle client 32 bit` on `windows 2012 64 bit` ?

2) Can we install Both (`oracle client 32 bit` and `Oracle client 64 bit`) on `windows 2012 64 bit` ?

Regards
Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for both questions.

When you like to install both 32 bit and 64 bit on one machine, follow this instruction: [BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

Otherwise you have to shuffle around with `PATH` and other environment values, resp. registry entries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Depending on the client applications you sometimes need both. You can install each in it's own Oracle home.